# Регистрация \ авторизация биллинг системы(другая cms) на основном сайте

Tags: авторизация, регистрация, php

Здравствуйте, вот задаюсь вопросом, как хостинг компании делают вход в панель управления или вход в биллинг прямо с сайта при этом там же регистрируются и авторизуются и перенаправляются в биллинг уже авторизованными... Я конечно любитель, поэтому мало знаю...
Кто знает, **ПОМОГИТЕ** пожалуйста!

Comment: Не совсем ясна задача, которую вы хотет решить, опишите подробнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если php то, [вот](http://forum.vingrad.ru/topic-130135.html) есть пост на форуме на эту тему

Comment: Спасибо за подсказу) это почти то, что я хотел знать))